How to get very fine tipped pens to write consistently?
I like to take notes in books and for that it’s really nice to have a pen that’s something like .28 but every time I get a pen that has these smaller tips they are very inconsistent.
Different writing pressures, angles, scribbing, shaking,  nothing seems to get them to consistently output.
Is there a trick to it or is this just a thing when the tip is small?
Edit: willing to update tags: writing, ink, and pen didn’t exist and I was running low on ideas of how to label this

Buy a more expensive pen?

If you don’t want to use pencil (see the other answer), choose a pen with a fiber tip, they have a more consistent ink flow than very fine ballpoint pens, especially if you’re using rather more pressure when writing - this can permanently damage a thin ballpoint in a very short time.
An example in a lower price range would be the Stabilo Fineliner, but you can find lots of alternatives, including very expensive ones, in stores carrying art supplies.
These tips will however need a bit of care, as they are sensitive to excessive pressure (as are all fine -tipped pens) and the will often adapt themselves to your writing angle after a while in the way or angle the top wears off (yes, paper is slightly abrasive). If you really struggle with keeping the pressure off, there are even fineliners with a spring loaded tip to compensate for that, but I can’t share a personal experience with them, having never used one myself.

My hack is to switch to using a mechanical pencil, which can be obtained in size 0.2 mm upwards.
The added bonus is that you can erase the notes you make in a book if you want to.

I'd recommend a fairly soft, black pencil lead, which makes notes show up clearly without indenting the paper much, and can be erased without leaving much of a mark.  I find 2B (UK/EU; = #0 US) 0.5mm works well for annotating music score, which is comparable.

@gidds I use the extra strong 0.7 HB leads, as I am more concerned with them not breaking too frequently when writing fast, than with a thin line.
